# VS Code C++ OOP don't work Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, oop, visual-studio-code, clang++

hello guys i'm new to vs code and i couldn't find a solution to use object oriented programming

when I create a .h file to call an object function I get an error

```
123MacBook-Pro-de-Rogerio: life DJMatrix $ cd "/ Users / DJMatrix / Documents / Classes / c ++ / life /" && g ++ main.cpp -o main && "/ Users / Dtrix / Documents / Classes / c ++ / life / "main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Life :: tryAgain ()", referenced from:
      _main in main-ea3ce4.o
ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Print]

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "life.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Life life;
    life.tryAgain();
    return 0;
}
```

**life.h:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Life
{
public:
    bool sucess;
  void tryAgain();
  void improve();
};
```

**life.cpp:**

```
#include "life.h"

void Life::tryAgain()
{
  cout << "Trying again!!!" << endl;
}

void Life::improve()
{
  cout << "Improve !!" << endl;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see from the VSCode terminal, only `main.cpp` is getting compiled. The object file for `life.cpp` is not getting linked when you produce the final binary, that's why it's complaining that the `Life::tryAgain()` symbol is missing.

This depends on whether you're invoking the compiler manually or using Makefiles or letting VSCode do all of this for you; regardless the compile command should look like:

`g++ -o main life.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: Is there a component or modification that automates this process?

Comment: @Matrix Look into creating a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_build-helloworldcpp) for compiling/building your application. You could set `g++` args to compile all `*.cpp` files in a directory.